# How to find the closed solution for the following recursive vector equations?

Tags: vectors

Let $\hat{v}_n=(\cos \theta_n,\sin \theta_n)$ be a unit vector where $\hat{v}_1=\hat{y}$ and let $\vec{r}_n=\vec{r}_{n-1}+\hat{v}_n$ where $\vec{r}_0=\hat{x}$, $\lvert\vec{r}_n\rvert=\sqrt{n+1}$ and $\vec{r}_{n-1}\cdot\hat{v}_n=0$.

How can we represent $\theta_n$ in a closed form?

Comment: Note that I have updated the question in $\vec{r}_{n-1}\cdot\hat{v}_n=0$.

Comment: I will give a bounty of 500 for the first correct answer!

Comment: $$\theta_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \cot^{-1} \sqrt{k}.$$  I don't believe this sum has a closed form expression.

Comment: @heropup: You can submit it as your answer, but don't forget to write the process. I will give you a bounty of 500 if it is the only possible solution.

Comment: @heropup: I think it should be $\sqrt{k-1}$
 rather than $\sqrt{k}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

taking the positive orientation and setting $r_n=\sqrt{n-1}e^{i\phi_n}$
$$
v_{n}=i\frac{r_{n-1}}{|r_{n-1}|}=r_n - r_{n-1}=ie^{i\phi_{n-1}}=e^{i\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\phi_{n-1}\right)}
$$
so it is enough to compute $\phi_n$ (always up to multiples of $2\pi$)
$$
r_n=i\frac{r_{n-1}}{|r_{n-1}|}+r_{n-1}=ie^{i\phi_{n-1}}+\sqrt{n}e^{i\phi_{n-1}}=(i+\sqrt{n})e^{i\phi_{n-1}}= \frac{i+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}} r_{n-1}
$$
so in every step an argument of $i+\sqrt{n}$ is added, which gives an infinite series (edit: of @heropup), and
$$
r_n = \left(1+\frac{i}{\sqrt{n}}\right)
 \left(1+\frac{i}{\sqrt{n-1}}\right)
 \left(1+\frac{i}{\sqrt{n-2}}\right)
 \dots
 \left(1+\frac{i}{\sqrt{1}}\right)
e^{i\phi_0}
$$
gives a clear geometrical picture of the process (a '*spiral*')

Comment: +1 but I am waiting for the complete solution. :-)

Comment: in principle you could compute the real and imaginary parts of the above product, which would give you a very, very ugly formula. I think that nothing better than the infinite series will be possible.

Comment: @heropup's solution in his comment seems to be much more better.

Comment: this is not a 'solution', it is the deduction of @heropup's formula

Comment: OK. I am waiting for other solutions if any.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_of_Theodorus